# Change lat long in google maps flutter for circle property

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am trying to build a flutter application which uses a google map integration. I wish to show a circle inside the google map. I am able to do it with static data, but I am not able to do it with the current location of the user.

Following is my code:

```
class Get_address extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _Get_addressState createState() => _Get_addressState();
}

class _Get_addressState extends State<Get_address> {

  GoogleMapController googleMapController;
  double zoomVal=5.0;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Position _currentPosition;
  TextEditingController _addressController;
  static const LatLng _mycenter = const LatLng(45.20212, -122.677892);

  Set<Circle> myCircles = Set.from([Circle(
  circleId: CircleId('1'),
  center: _mycenter,
  radius: 4000,
  )]);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Choose a location to see what\'s available',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlue[900],
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                _buildGoogleMap(context),
                _zoomminusfunction(),
                _zoomplusfunction(),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: getCurrentLoaction,
              child: Text('Press'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _zoomminusfunction() {

    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.searchMinus,color:Color(0xff6200ee)),
          onPressed: () {
            zoomVal--;
            _minus( zoomVal);
          }),
    );
  }
  Widget _zoomplusfunction() {

    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.searchPlus,color:Color(0xff6200ee)),
          onPressed: () {
            zoomVal++;
            _plus(zoomVal);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGoogleMap(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 425,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition:  CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: 12),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        circles: myCircles,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _minus(double zoomVal) async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: zoomVal)));
  }
  Future<void> _plus(double zoomVal) async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: zoomVal)));
  }

  void getCurrentLoaction() async{
    Geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() async {
        _currentPosition = position;
        PermissionStatus permission;
        permission = await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions();
        final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
        controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(_currentPosition.latitude,_currentPosition.longitude), zoom: 15,tilt: 50.0,
            bearing: 45.0,)));
        _mycenter = LatLng(_currentPosition.latitude,_currentPosition.longitude);
      });

    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

When I am trying to change the value of _mycenter in the getCurrentLoaction() method, it says:

```
Constant variables can't be assigned a value.
```

But if I don't make _mycenter as a constant, it shows error in the MyCircles declaration. It says:

```
The instance member '_mycenter' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is because of const keyword.
And second issue is because of static keyword.

Solution : `LatLng _mycenter` instead of `static const LatLng _mycenter`

Comment: Could you provide working code examples and details about the issue and why/how your solution will fix the issue?

Comment: That is what I mentioned that if I remove them then I won't be able to initialize it in the first place

Comment: You can initialise it in initState(), not directly while declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function where you build your circles and call that in the maps.
So:

```
...
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition:  CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: 12),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        circles: _buildCircles(), //here the function
      ),
...
```

and the function:

```
 Set<Circle> _buildCircles(){
   return Set.from([Circle(
  circleId: CircleId('1'),
  center: _mycenter,
  radius: 4000,
  )]);
 }
```

Anytime you call setState, the widget tree redraw and your maps will create the circles with the new _mycenter location.

Comment: I tried that but now the circle is not even displaying in the predefined location